# What would happen if dd receives same input file as output file

Tags: linux, terminal, hard-disk, dd, cloning

Let's say I accidentally ran `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sda` instead of `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

And I didn't want to wait for the 500gb operation to complete to find out if I broke my system.

Does anyone know what the outcome would be so I can either wait in peace for it to complete or just interrupt it and start with a fresh install so long?

Edit: Here is the resulting output

```
$ time sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sda bs=64K conv=sync,noerror status=progress
512001769472 bytes (512 GB, 477 GiB) copied, 9084 s, 56.4 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device
7814181+1 records in
7814181+0 records out
512110190592 bytes (512 GB, 477 GiB) copied, 9088.72 s, 56.3 MB/s

real    151m28.774s
user    0m28.459s
sys 5m33.146s
```

Comment: You could try this yourself with a disposable loopback image file

Comment: When you are ready to clone the disk, just use `sudo -s` and then carefully `cat /dev/sda >/dev/sdb`. It's way, way faster than the command you intended to use.

Comment: @roaima thanks i will try cat

Comment: @DanBalzeer You did not mention the additional options previously. See [`dd conv=sync,noerror` corrupts your data.](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171) I assume this affects you because normally the "no space left on device" is not possible when reading/writing to the same device.

Comment: Never mind, it'll probably because your device is not multiples of 64K large, so it tried to write more zeroes for the last sector only (check device size with `blockdev --getsize64` and see if it divides by 65536). It would likely have corrupted your data if it actually encountered real read errors, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In isolation, `dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdx` would write the same data that is already there. No harm done(*).

However, if the device is in active use e.g. by a filesystem, there may be a possible race condition:

dd reads data (A), filesystem writes data (B), dd writes data (A), causing (B) to be lost / corrupted.

So it could still result in data loss or system crash.

Other possible side effects are wasting write cycles if it's SSD storage, and causing sparse files / thin volumes / snapshots to use up more storage space.

---

Also note that if you do the same thing with a regular file instead of a block device, the result would be an empty file and all data lost:

```
$ dd if=foobar of=foobar
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000179684 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

That's because without `conv=notrunc` the first thing `dd` does is truncate the output file to 0 bytes, and at that time, all it can read from a 0 byte file is 0 bytes too.

---

(*) unless you use additional options that are capable of changing offsets, such as `seek`, `skip`, `noerror`, `sync`, ... or if you end up using different but same device like `if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdx1` where such offsets are introduced by partitioning. In this case `dd` would end up writing the same data pattern repeatedly (by reading what it previously wrote at an offset). It would corrupt everything.

There is also a more obscure corner case where a device erratically returns wrong data without properly reporting it as a read error. In this case you'd end up writing corrupt data back to the device.

Comment: I don't get the first part *"possible race condition:"* dd won't work on mounted drive

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen as the data is read, buffered, written (in that order)